# Why my vertical tab js code is refreshing the page continuously?

Tags: jquery, javascript, admin

I am currently making the vertical tab for theme option in WordPress admin area. The code for vertical tab is taken from [W3school vertical tab](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_vertical_tabs)

**So what's the problem**

The problem is the code is refreshing the page continuously.

**Here is the code**

```
// Verticall Tabs
function openCity(evt, cityName) {
    var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
    tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
    for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
        tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
    }
    tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("dr_v_tablinks");
    for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
        tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
    }
    document.getElementById(cityName).style.display = "block";
    evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
}

// Get the element with id="defaultOpen" and click on it
document.getElementById("defaultOpen").click();
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and didn't find the answer. But I also find a solution without JavaScript. You can do tabs only with CSS+HTML.
It is something like:

---

CSS:

```
<style type="text/css">
        #tabs div
        {
            width: 200px;
            padding: 25px 0;
            margin: 0;
            position: relative;
        }

        #contents div
        {
            display: none;
            position: absolute;
            left: 200px;
            top: 0;
            width: 200%;
            margin-left: 20px;
        }

        #contents div:target
        {
            display: block;
        }
      //And add more features to make it pretty
    </style>
```

HTML:

```
<div id="tabs">
    <div id="menu">
       <ul>
           <li><a href="#1">Datos 1</a></li>
           <li><a href="#2">2</a></li>
           <li><a href="#3">3</a></li>
       </ul>
     </div>
     <div id="contents">
          <div id="1" class="tabcontent">1</div>
          <div id="2" class="tabcontent">2</div>
          <div id="3" class="tabcontent">3</div>
     </div>
     </div>


//Sería un ejemplo básico
```